# Arquitectura de base de datos independientes para cada cliente

Tags: django, base-de-datos, postgresql

**Objetivo.** Debo desarrollar un proyecto con Django y quiero que tenga la siguiente característica: por cada empresa o cliente (sea empresa o no) que use mi sistema, quiero que se cree una base de datos independiente.

Básicamente lo que quiero es que el sistema tenga "superusuarios", y que los datos de cada uno de ellos tenga una base de datos. Por cada superusuario habrá una empresa y usuarios del sistema de esa empresa.

**Lo que investigué.** Me he [encontrado](http://gravitar.biz/tecnologia-negocios/arquitecturas-multi-tenant/) con las siguientes opciones:

1. que cada cliente tenga su propia base de datos independiente
2. que haya una base de datos en común para todos los clientes, pero cada cliente tiene su propio esquema independiente.
3. (no es lo que quiero) una base de datos en común para todos los clientes y que los datos de cada uno se identifican con una FK en cada una de las tablas.

**Pregunta.** ¿Es posible utilizar nua base de datos independiente por cliente con Django? ¿Cómo se haría?

**Intentos.** Encontré un paquete llamado "django multi tenant postgresql" (o algo similar).
No me queda claro si es lo que se puede hacer con este paquete

Comment: Creo que la pregunta se entiende, pero ¿qué es específicamente lo que no te queda claro? Quizás podrías describir con más detalle hasta qué punto te imaginás llegar y dónde te cuesta seguir la implementación.

Comment: Me dieron un paquete llamado "django multi tenant postgresql" o algo similar

Comment: Basicamente lo quw quiero es que el sistema tenga "superusuarios", y que los datos de cada uno de ellos tenga una base de datos. Por cada superusuario habra una empresa y usuarios del sistema de esa empresa

Comment: He estado leyendo por ahi, y me he encontrado con lo siguiente:

1) que cada cliente tenga su propia base de datos independiente
2) que haya una base de datos en comun para todos los clientes, pero cada cliente tiene su propio esquema independiente

hay un tercero que bueno, no es lo que quiero, que es una base de datos en comun para todos los clientes y que los datos de cada uno se identifican con una FK en cada una de las tablas.

A mi me interesa el primer caso, una base independiente para cada cliente, y ahi no me queda claro si es lo que se puede hacer con este paquete

Comment: http://gravitar.biz/tecnologia-negocios/arquitecturas-multi-tenant/

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer es definir por cada modelo una relación "ForeignKey" "ManytoMany" o "OneToOne" segun sea el caso, al modelo User `django.contrib.auth.models`.

Comment: Explica mejor tu respuesta, por qué ese código y como ayuda a solucionarlo